# How to get a variable from url and 301 redirect with php?

Tags: php, apache, redirect, http-status-code-301

I want to get a variable from the url and 301 redirect visitors to new domain and include that variable in the new url in php.

For example, visitor comes to my site http://example.com/?id=abc on that site I have an index.php file that has this kind of code on it:

```
<?php 
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header("Location: http://www.New-Website.com/?id=$_GET["id"]"); 
?>
```

I want to 301 redirect the visitors to a new website with the same variable.

This code gives me error 500.

I know this could be done in .htaccess but I need to do it in php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a double quote inside a double quoted string

So amend `$_GET["id"]` to

```
header("Location: http://www.New-Website.com/?id=$_GET[id]");
```

Or

```
header("Location: http://www.New-Website.com/?id={$_GET['id']}");
```

Answer (score 1):

Error in the second line. Double quotes are not escaped. It is advisable to take out of the location and using concatenation. 
Even better, and specify the type of data

```
<?php 
 header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
 header("Location: New-Website.com/?id=".(int)$_GET["id"]);
```

Comment: Why should the OP ___try this___? **Good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: Sry. 
Error in the second line. Double quotes are not escaped. It is advisable to take out of the location and using concatenation. Even better, and specify the type of data header("Location: http://www.New-Website.com/?id=".(int)$_GET["id"]);

Answer (score 1):

If you are using apache, just add a `.htaccess` file in root of your old domain with the content:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.New-Website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and all the requests to old domain will be redirected to a new one

see example [here](http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=b5d36dad-48c1-5461-aff6-9752e14b8499)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location:http://www.New-Website.com/?". $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
exit;?>
```

Comment: This answer doesn't address the actual problem in the question (it's just a syntax error) and doesn't contain any explanation for the code, which makes it not so useful.